# What is the purpose of the "rich text" button on NSTextFields on cocoa?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, interface-builder, nstextfield

I mean, `NSTextField`s have attributted text properties, right? So, what is the purpose of this "rich text" option on interface builder for `NSTextField`s on cocoa?

As usual, no documentation about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextField/setAllowsEditingTextAttributes:):

> If YES, and the text value is an attributed string, it is displayed
>   using the attributed string’s visual settings, which can be modified
>   in the font panel.; if flag is NO and the text is an attributed
>   string. the string attributes (font, color, etc.) are ignored and the
>   string is displayed based on the text field’s settings. Setting the
>   attributed string’s attributes are ignored when displaying the string
>   and when the text field is editing.

Actually, the way it appears to work if *RichText* is disabled with regards to the Font Panel is that the Font, Color, etc. **is** actually changed - just *for the whole text*, not just the selected section/characters...

Comment: so what you are telling me is this: on interface builder we have this `title` field. This filed can be regular or attributted text, depending on if the "rich text" box is checked or not, right? If this is true, then interface builder is once more, crappy, for several reasons: first, it gives you a regular text field called `title` to add both non-attributed and attributed text and second because if I turn "rich text" off the label continues to show the text as attributed on interface builder. Apple is doing a good job with Xcode. It is now ready to dump on the garbage can. 